# is there a ubuntu to android screen share tool?

Tags: android, screen, airplay

I do a lot of face to face software demos, and I want to show the customer a tablet and screen share my desktop, it's way less awkward than having them sit next to me.  Is there an airplay equivalent for Ubuntu where I can share my screen with a vanilla Android tablet?

Comment: Sounds like it would be easier to just run an android emulator...

Answer (score 0):

It's relatively easy to do. Just enable remote desktop sharing on your Ubuntu computer, and then use a vnc client on the android tablet.

So for example, on the kde desktop, use krfb. I think on gnome you use remote desktop sharing from system settings.

Any vnc client on android should work.

Don't forget to allow the incoming connection through your linux firewall.

I would not recommend this for internet access though, only on a local network.